# Why my rigging pose didnt change/move after render?

Tags: rendering, rigging, blender-internal-render-engine, pose-mode

i made character with rigging and put keyframe with locrot on pose mode, in preview my character was sucsessfully moving, but when i try to render animation but the character not move at all. Am i missiing something?
[image: armature was visible in render]

Comment: May be the armature modifier visibile in viewport and invisible in render. Check it in the modifier properies tab.

Comment: @FFeller checked and all object is on visible in viewport and visible in render

Comment: Not, the object, its modifier. You can hide it too.